# Centered CSS pages that are longer than one screen appear 5px~ further to the left than shorter ones - how do I stop this?

Tags: css, screen, center

This problem has been perplexing me for a while now, and I've tried researching it but so far I've just turned up sites that tell me how to center things but that's not the problem. The problem is that while #content looks like it's centered, when the page takes up more than one screen it causes the #content to appear about 5px to the left of where it appears when it is less than one screen in height. Is there a way to fix this without forcing my shorter pages to reach the bottom screen or beyond?

Here's how I'm centering my content:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#content {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
}
```

I'll admit that there's a couple more divs in there, but I don't that's really relevant to this problem...

Comment: Isn't that just because an approximate 10px wide scrollbar is added on the right?  i.e. the content has to move, to remain centered in the non-scrollbar occupied viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS will force the vertical sidebar to appear, even on pages that are shorter than the viewport height. This will prevent the horizontal shift that you're noticing.

```
html {
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Via http://egilhansen.com/2007/03/28/css-trick-always-show-scrollbars/

Answer (score 1):

[@asc99c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/382166/asc99c) is right.

The scroll bar is causing your problem.

When it appears, it pushes everything over.

To solve this (if you must), you could make your pages taller than 100%.  Something like

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
}

div{
    height:101%;
}
```

With `div` being your main content `div`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/7NYnS/